# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to a VM using this command:

```
sudo ssh -i /home/ritesh/.ssh/id_rsa1 tc@54.80.22.15 -L 5901:localhost:5901
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
The authenticity of host '54.80.22.15 (54.80.22.15)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is X.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

you need to copy your public key to VM, it's not recognized your public key so add
it

```
$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa1.pub tc@54.80.22.15:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or also try it

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa1.pub | ssh tc@[your.ip.address.here] "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```